# Are the councilman's comments random?

Tags: xcom-2

I just made a month with 0 alien activity 4 blocks on the avatar project and like 2x contact 3x radio beacons 2 guerilla ops and 1 retaliation with only 1 civil dying and 2 flawless missions and the councilman tells me, he is sad to notify that my actions are seen as "mediocre".

So I started getting the impression he just throws in random voice lines.
Is that the case?

Comment: A four blocks month is mediocre ;) It's like a third of the overall bar. In my experience the voice lines seem to be tied to the avatar project only. The council doesn't care about radios, regions and the like in the monthly report. If your month didn't have anything to reduce the Avatar project you won't get an A.

Comment: @Helmar: That makes no sense. He just prised how I outdid his expectations when I was on 9ish blocks just in that previous month.

Comment: It's not about how high the bar is but how much progress each side made. If the bar moves to the left it's good, if it's moving to the right it's bad. I think it's about two blocks or so he tolerates. If you did any story missions or progress you get a better rating too. Of course most story mission months won't have more than 2 bars delta for the aliens.

Comment: @Helmar: That makes no sense either. as said I was in the previous month on 9ish blocks so zero alien activity included that I moved from 9 to 4 while they did nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three types of responses. You get the worst response when you fail two missions that month and do not reduce the timer at all. You get the mediocre response when you fail at least 1 mission or if you succeed all missions, but do not reduce the doom timer and the doom timer is 2/3rd of the way to the end. Otherwise you get the good ending.

Relevant code from the ModBuddy: `XComGameState_HeadquartersResistance.uc`

```
DoomRatio = (AlienHQ.GetCurrentDoom() * 1.0) / AlienHQ.GetMaxDoom();

if (iMissionsFailed >= 2 && iDoomReduced == 0)
{
    return 'MonthlyReport_Bad';
}
else if (iMissionsFailed >= 1 || (iDoomReduced == 0 && DoomRatio >= 0.66))
{
    return 'MonthlyReport_Moderate';
}
else
{
    return 'MonthlyReport_Good';
}
```

Comment: Is doom timer the timer after avatar progress is 100%? or is doom the avatar progress? If the first is the case, how can I reduce that timer at all? If the second is the case, it still doesn't seem to fit. as 4 blocks isn't 2/3 and I failed no mission at all (as I'm min/maxing.)

Comment: The doom timer is the thing with 10 blocks in the top. I would need to do some more research if we want to know what it considers a mission, and why it considers it bad. It checks a boolean `bAlwaysBad`, and I believe it might consider a Dark Event to be a mission, even though there is no way you can win one.

Comment: Hmmm weird, as said the month had 0 alien activity. I actually had 2 guerrilla ops in that month making it possible for me to shut down all dark events and literally not having any alien activity. But NVM for the scope of the question you have answered me if its random or isn't. His reaction in it self I'll just consider as bug. As said I'm min/maxing and did quiet a lot reloading. Maybe some states that influenced the spokesmen had been accessed on the wrong place or w/e.

Comment: Looking at the config file, the following activity resolutions count towards `iMissionsFailed`: `ResAct_RetaliationsFailed`, `ResAct_GuerrillaOpsFailed`, `ResAct_CouncilMissionsFailed`, `ResAct_SupplyRaidsFailed`, `ResAct_LandedUFOsFailed`. Dark events, alien facilities built and avatar progress are also marked bad, but are not (or should not) be marked as mission.